# Passing a vector as a reference to a recursive function

Tags: c++, vector

I've build a function that accepts a reference to a vector as argument, it looks like this :

```
void func(std::vector<int> &vec) {
   // sth. to do
}
```

But i want that the function is recursive and calls itself with a part of the original vector.

```
void func(std::vector<int> &vec) {
    // sth. to do
    func(part of the orignial vector);
}
```

How can i construct a new vector from my original vector ? It's important that when I modify the part of the vector in the recursive call, that the original vector "vec" has also this changes, so i didn't wan't to pass a copy or new vector.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pass a couple of iterators. That's the way all the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) operate. Then it's easy to pass any subrange of the original input range.

Comment: Or "the old way", you can pass starting/ending indexes along with the array.

Comment: or with [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), pass a *range* instead of a vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old way!

```
void func(std::vector<int> &vec,int l,int r) {
    // this function modifies only vec fro indices l to r. 
    //
    // do what you want
    //
    //
    func(vec,new_l,new_r);
}
```

Comment: Consider using `size_t` for the indices, otherwise the code may have an exploit if the vector size can exceed `INT_MAX`. Actually one of the main reasons to prefer using `vector::iterator` is to avoid this issue entirely